# Single Link to generate a Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a link to google map where an image is generated by reading the parameters passed the link. Here is the code:

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Madison,%20WI&amp;zoom=14&amp;size=288x200&amp;markers=Madison,%20WI&amp;sensor=false" height="200" width="288" />
```

My question is:

It there any way to generated a google map instead of a map image in this same way where I have a single line of code with parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://www.geocodezip.com/example_geo2.asp?addr1=Madison,%20WI&geocode=1&zoom=14

(it is a Google Maps API v2 example, that API is deprecated, but something similar could be created with the Google Maps API v3)